# android things preview camera2 reader.acquireLatestImage and reader.acquirePreviusImage

Tags: android-things

Im trying to preview on Android things, I understand that when you preview and display it does not work so I am trying to create a preview and just access the reader.acquireLatestImage and reader.acquirePreviusImage OnImageAvailable Listerner, my code executes and suddenly closes camera,I get a camera close error. This is my Preview Session code:

```
public void createCameraPreviewSession() {
        try {

        Log.d("PI Camera", "On createCameraPreviewSession");

        mImageReaderPreview = ImageReader.newInstance(640, 480, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 1);
        mImageReaderPreview.setOnImageAvailableListener(mOnPreviewAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);



        // We set up a CaptureRequest.Builder with the output Surface.
        mPreviewRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);

        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageReaderPreview.getSurface());

        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList( mImageReaderPreview.getSurface()), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback()
        {@Override
        public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
            // The camera is already closed
            if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                Log.d("PI Camera", "On createCameraPreviewSession:  Camera already closed");
                return;
            }

            // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
            mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
            Log.d("PI Camera", "On createCameraPreviewSession:  Previewing ready");

            try {
                // Auto focus should be continuous for camera preview.
                mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO);

                // Finally, we start displaying the camera preview.
                mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
                Log.d("PI Camera", "On createCameraPreviewSession:  Previewing start");
                mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest, mCaptureCallback, null);

            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                Log.d("PI Camera", "On createCameraPreviewSession:  Previewing Error"+ e.toString());

        }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Camera Configuration failed!");}},BackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here is my LogCat, it has some sphal errors:

```
10-25 07:00:27.460 18787-18787/? I/zygote: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
10-25 07:00:27.628 18787-18787/? W/zygote: Using default instruction set 
features for ARM CPU variant (generic) using conservative defaults
10-25 07:00:27.686 18787-18796/? I/zygote: Ignoring second debugger -- 
accepting and dropping
10-25 07:00:28.170 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback 
I/CameraManagerGlobal: Connecting to camera service
10-25 07:00:28.176 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback D/PiCamera: Using 
camera id 0
10-25 07:00:28.247 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback D/PiCamera: Camera 
Opened
10-25 07:00:28.261 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback D/ContentValues: 
Directory already available
10-25 07:00:28.262 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback D/Path:: 
/data/user/0/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback/app_OpenALPR/Tester000.png
10-25 07:00:28.386 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback W/DynamiteModule: 
Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not 
found.
10-25 07:00:28.415 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback W/zygote: Skipping 
duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
10-25 07:00:28.423 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback I/DynamiteModule: 
Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:0 and remote 
module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:1101
10-25 07:00:28.424 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback I/DynamiteModule: 
Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite, version 
>= 1101
10-25 07:00:28.520 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback W/zygote: Skipping 
duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
10-25 07:00:28.626 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback I/Vision: Loading 
library libocr.so
10-25 07:00:28.688 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback I/Vision: libocr.so 
library load status: true
10-25 07:00:28.690 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback I/Vision: Reading 
ocr models from /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/files/com.google.android.gms.vision/ocr/data/models
10-25 07:00:28.693 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback I/native: 
jni_helper.cc:76 Loading model config /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/files/com.google.android.gms.vision/ocr/data
/models/mognet_lstm_engine_0.7.bincfg
10-25 07:00:28.697 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback I/native: 
timer.h:126 PhotoOcrEngine::Init (detector): 0.376 ms (elapsed)
10-25 07:00:28.711 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback I/native: 
mognet_classifier_client.cc:1810 Using full specialization.
10-25 07:00:28.714 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback I/native: 
timer.h:126 PhotoOcrEngine::Init (classifier): 16.983 ms (elapsed)
10-25 07:00:28.795 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback I/native: 
timer.h:126 PhotoOcrEngine::Init (recognizer): 80.651 ms (elapsed)
10-25 07:00:28.795 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback I/native: 
timer.h:126 void ocr::photo::PhotoOcrEngine::Init(): 98.518 ms (elapsed)
10-25 07:00:28.805 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback D/OCR: Libraries 
Installed successfully
10-25 07:00:29.629 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback D/OCR: 3
10-25 07:00:29.630 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback D/OCR: OCR: 1RLD
10-25 07:00:29.630 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback D/OCR: OCR: THE 
QUICK
                                                                      BROWN   FOX JKHJSDK)
10-25 07:00:29.631 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback D/OCR: OCR: 
SCOOOOPI!

KLDJLGJ
10-25 07:00:29.631 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback D/OCR: OCR: com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextBlock@d871e16com.google.android.gms.visio
n.text.TextBlock@8b6b397com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextBlock@e4ca984
10-25 07:00:29.713 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback D/PiCamera: Opened 
camera.
10-25 07:00:29.715 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback D/PI Camera: On 
createCameraPreviewSession
10-25 07:00:29.831 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback D/PI Camera: On 
createCameraPreviewSession:  Previewing ready
10-25 07:00:29.834 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback D/PI Camera: On 
createCameraPreviewSession:  Previewing start
10-25 07:00:29.857 18787-18801/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback I/vndksupport: sphal 
namespace is not configured for this process. Loading 
/vendor/lib/hw/gralloc.gbm.so from the current namespace instead.
10-25 07:00:29.867 18787-18801/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback I/vndksupport: sphal 
namespace is not configured for this process. Loading 
/vendor/lib/hw/gralloc.gbm.so from the current namespace instead.
10-25 07:00:29.945 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback D/PiCamera: Camera 
device error, closing. Error ID = 4
10-25 07:00:30.169 18787-18787/com.demoiot.Gwed.camback D/PiCamera: Closed 
camera, releasing
```

Comment: You need full logcat from the whole system, not just your app logcat here.  It'll likely tell you more about the camera error that's happening.  The sphal logs don't show anything concerning, just some unnecessary logging from the HAL loading subsystem.